# Php session variable returns another variable

Tags: php, variables, session

I don't understand the next declaration:

```
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'LANG VARIABLE';
$_SESSION['lang_vars'] = 'LANG VARS';

echo $_SESSION['lang']; // Return text "LANG VARIABLE"
$lang = $_SESSION['lang_vars'];
echo $_SESSION['lang']; // Return text "LANG VARS"
exit();
```

On my wamp server there is no error like this, but up on server i Got this...

There must be as php.ini setting that I don't know or what ?

Comment: Try register_globals in php.ini

Comment: *"but up on server i Got this..."* - Got what?

Comment: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. When on, register_globals will inject your scripts with all sorts of variables, like request variables from HTML forms. This can write insecure code with this directive but keep in mind that the directive itself isn't insecure but rather it's the misuse of it. This is from php.net.

Comment: Can you try calling `session_start()` before all this? Might be a fix.

Comment: In my cpanel from hosting says that register_globals = Off and executing phpinfo() says: register_globals: Local Value On | Master Value Off. Using php_flag register_globals 0 in htaccess file returns the same error / problem. So ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet the [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) option is enabled on the server. You can check this with [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Create a `.htaccess` file with the following content and place it in the root www folder on the server:

```
php_flag register_globals 0
```